# Is a reference to String a pointer to a String variable or a pointer to its ptr member?

Tags: rust

I saw this image while reading "the book" (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#references-and-borrowing):

[image: reference representation in Rust]

I have two questions：

1. Does reference `s` point to `s1` itself (address of struct `s1`) or the member `ptr` of `s1`?
2. Is `s` (the reference) itself a Struct that contains a public member `ptr` or a pointer (`string* s`) like in C++?

For easier understanding:

```rust
fn main() {
    // String
    let s1 = String::from("hello");

    // reference
    let s = &s1;

    println!("s:{:p}, s1:{:p}", s, &s1);
    // OUTPUT: s:0x63373afae0, s1:0x63373afae0

}
```

Comment: Is this a visualization of `let s = &s1` where `let s1 = "hello".to_string()`?

Comment: In Rust, references tend to behave like pointers but with all sorts of other checks, like borrow checking, no ability to create "null" references, etc.

Comment: Where did you see this picture?

Comment: You should include the context of how `s` and `s1` are defined in their example.

Comment: @tadman I saw it in the Rust book, I have added the link, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does reference `s` point to `s1` itself (address of struct `s1`) or the member `ptr` of `s1`?

It is pointing on the whole struct.

> Is `s` (the reference) itself a Struct that contains a public member `ptr` or a pointer (`string* s`) like in C++?

A pointer; references are a primitive.

Comment: _"both have the same address"_ How can you be sure of this?

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger Because that's what the figure shows :) Not because I know the layout of `String` of course.

Comment: The figure merely shows a possible arrangement of fields within struct `String`. `s` and `s1` are part of a code snippet. The way they are arranged and padded in memory is unspecified, so they might not always "have the same address".

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger Ok, got your opinion. Will edit.

Comment: But the Slice type is also a pointer, it should be a Struct, right? Because it has two public fileds: ptr and length: Struct fatPointer {pub ptr, pub length},

Comment: @Yang Slices are also primitives. We also have to differentiate between the slice type itself, which is a DST, and the reference to it, which is not. It is true that if it wasn't defined we could define a reference to a slice using other primitives as a struct (although not with all of its features, e.g. custom syntax and coercions from arrays), but it is built into the compiler. There is nowehere in std a declaration `struct [T]`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I see, I mistook the Slice type and the reference to Slice as the same thing. Thank you